# Как вывести в execute в Telegram бот текст с нижним подчеркиванием

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Всем привет, задача такая, вывести сообщение в телеграм боте **с нижним** подчеркиванием!
В данном примере не выводится, выдает ошибку:
Ошибка:

```
Error executing org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage query: [400] Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 0
```

```
private void vivod(Message command, Update update) {
    String al = "previer_var_12";;
    try {
        execute(
                SendMessage.builder()
                        .chatId(command.getChatId())
                        .parseMode("Markdown")
                        .text(al)
                        .build()
        );
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Если же в переменной al убрать _, например "previer var", то все ОК

Пробовал экранировать так:

```
private void vivod(Message command, Update update) {
    String al = "previer_var_12";
    al.replace("_","\\_");
//  al.replaceAll("_", "%5f") - так тоже пробовал
    try {
        execute(
                SendMessage.builder()
                        .chatId(command.getChatId())
                        .parseMode("Markdown")
                        .text(al)
                        .build()
        );
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Не помогло
Еще пробовал так:

```
String al = "first_second_nickName";
String vv;
int index1 = al.indexOf('_');
if (index1 == -1) {
    vv = al;
} else {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(al);
    vv = String.valueOf(sb.insert(index1, "\\"));
    System.out.println(vv);
}
    execute(
            SendMessage.builder()
                    .chatId(command.getChatId())
                    .parseMode("Markdown")
                    .text(vv)
                    .build()
    );
```

Помогает только с первым нижним подчеркиванием, то есть если **first_secondnickName**, то все нормально, но если появляется второе нижнее подчеркивание: **first_second_nickName**, уже не выводит. Как засунуть в цикл поиск _ и вставка перед ней "\"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сделали замену, но проигнорировали результат. Присвойте результат замены к новой переменной:

```java
String result = text.replace("_", "\\_");
```